# Interpret the term 'County' in the HERE Geocoder Autocomplete Search

Tags: here-api

**Use Case:** I've got a search box that uses the autocomplete API to search by location, and one of the location types that needs to be searchable is County. However, the actual word "County" does not return county results, and when counties show up in the search results, they are not labeled as such.

**For example:** in a search for "San Diego", the first result is San Diego *County*, but it is labeled as "United States, CA, San Diego". The second result is the *city* of San Diego, which is labeled as "United States, CA, San Diego, San Diego".

Then, if I search for "San Diego County", the results do not include the county, but instead things like "County Road" somewhere in San Diego.

**Desired Outcome:** The goal is to be able to search for "San Diego County" and get "United States, CA, San Diego County" as the first result. After looking through the documentation, I didn't see any property to enable such an option. Is there a way to get this to work, without implementing a hack to modify the user's search string?

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is a county information then you dont need to add a searchText. You can directly provide county=San Diego in your query like below. Hope this helps.

```
https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?gen=9&app_id=xxxx&app_code=xxxx&county=San%20Diego
```

Result:

```
Relevance   1
MatchLevel  "county"
MatchQuality    
County  1
LocationId  "NT_Vmymhe8uceoG6bTzBwp5pA"
LocationType    "area"
DisplayPosition 
Latitude    33.01981
Longitude   -116.69382
NavigationPosition  
0   
Latitude    33.01981
Longitude   -116.69382
MapView 
TopLeft 
Latitude    33.50534
Longitude   -118.60739
BottomRight 
Latitude    32.53429
Longitude   -116.08098
Address 
Label   "San Diego, CA, United States"
Country "USA"
State   "CA"
County  "San Diego"
AdditionalData  
0   
value   "United States"
key "CountryName"
1   
value   "California"
key "StateName"
2   
value   "San Diego"
key "CountyName"
```

Comment: That is helpful- however, for my use case I'd want to search for counties, cities, addresses, etc. in the same search box (so using the same search query).

Comment: Another issue I ran into is searching by state abbreviation- for example, "Spokane, WA", does not return the city of Spokane in Washington, but rather results for the street "Spokane Way".

Comment: I tried the below query and was able to get Spokane in Washington.  Check your query or paste the query in which you dont get expected result. https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?gen=9&app_id=xxxx&app_code=xxxx&searchText=%22Spokane,%20WA%22.

Comment: I was using the geocoder autocomplete API (autocomplete.geocoder.api.here.com) rather than the standard geocoder API.